# Google API double calls

Tags: google-api

I have a problem with Google API

I have this js

```
(function() {
var po = document.createElement('script');
po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js?';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
})();
var myParams = {
   'clientid' : 'asdasdsad',
   'cookiepolicy' : 'none',
   'callback' : 'loginCallback', //callback function
   'approvalprompt':'auto',
   'accesstype':'online',
   'scope' : 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read'
};

function login()
{
  gapi.auth.signIn(myParams);
}

function loginCallback(result)
{
    if(result['status']['signed_in'])
    {
         console.log("signed");
    } else {
        console.log(result);
        console.log("secondo if");
    }

}
```

and the html:

```
<a href="#" id="g-btn" ><img src="{{ app.request.getBaseURL }}images/google.png" id="iconsocial" alt="google+" onclick="login()"></a>
```

When I click on href, in the console I see 2 calls at the API with the **immediate_failed**

Why is this?